# Python 2.7. If string found in 2 or more lines, keep only the first line

Tags: python, regex, duplicates

I have a huge file that looks like this:

```
CAV-1 ATCTACTTCTATCG
CAV-2 GCGCGTAGCTAGCT
CAV-2 AAGCGCTCGTAAAA
CAV-3 AAATATATATATCC
```

Using Python, I want to delete the lines having a duplicate string, in this case "CAV-2". The first line having the string would remain. I would get this:

```
CAV-1 ATCTACTTCTATCG
CAV-2 GCGCGTAGCTAGCT
CAV-3 AAATATATATATCC
```

I know how to use regex and to parse through lines, but I am not able to do this specific task.

I know how to use

Comment: is your file always sorted?

Comment: split lines, put the first part as key in a dict and check for each line if the first part is in already a dict key.

Comment: Hi @Psidom, I don't want to delete duplicate lines, I want to delete lines containing a duplicate regex. This is the function that is familiar to me, but other alternatives are welcome.

Comment: If the list can be unordered, or may be sorted later, you could use a set, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Comment: If it were sorted list within the string, a solution could be _Find_ `(?m)^((\S+)(?=\s).*\r?\n)\s*^\2(?=\s).*(?:\r?\n)?` _Replace_ `$1` https://regex101.com/r/X9HLww/1

Comment: Or, a multiple version https://regex101.com/r/X9HLww/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other users have pointed out, regex is not the best technique for this problem. You can use a dictionary, then remove duplicates:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
s = ["CAV-1 ATCTACTTCTATCG", "CAV-2 GCGCGTAGCTAGCT", "CAV-2 AAGCGCTCGTAAAA", "CAV-3 AAATATATATATCC"]
for name, sequence in [i.split() for i in s]:
   d[name].append(sequence)
final_output = [' '.join([a, b[0]]) for a, b in d.items()]
```

Output:

```
['CAV-1 ATCTACTTCTATCG', 'CAV-2 GCGCGTAGCTAGCT', 'CAV-3 AAATATATATATCC']
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use a dictionary

```
In [1]: lines = '''CAV-1 ATCTACTTCTATCG
   ...: CAV-2 GCGCGTAGCTAGCT
   ...: CAV-2 AAGCGCTCGTAAAA
   ...: CAV-3 AAATATATATATCC'''

In [2]: lines
Out[2]: 'CAV-1 ATCTACTTCTATCG\nCAV-2 GCGCGTAGCTAGCT\nCAV-2 AAGCGCTCGTAAAA\nCAV-3 AAATATATATATCC'

In [3]: res = {}

In [4]: for line in lines.split("\n"):
   ...:         res[line.split(" ")[0]] = line.split(" ")[1]
   ...:  

In [5]: res
Out[5]: 
{'CAV-1': 'ATCTACTTCTATCG',
 'CAV-2': 'AAGCGCTCGTAAAA',
 'CAV-3': 'AAATATATATATCC'}

In [6]: '\n'.join(['%s %s' % (key, value) for (key, value) in res.items()])
Out[6]: 'CAV-1 ATCTACTTCTATCG\nCAV-2 AAGCGCTCGTAAAA\nCAV-3 AAATATATATATCC'
```

If you want to preserve the first line you can use a dictionary of lists and then output the last element

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use capturing groups like this.

**Regex:** `((CAV-\d\s)[AGCT]+)(?:\n\2[AGCT]+)*`

**Explanation:**

1. `((CAV-\d\s)[AGCT]+)` checks for your pattern and captures whole match. Sub-match `CAV-\d\s` is captured in 2nd capturing group.
2. `(?:\n\2[AGCT]+)*` checks for more than one occurrence with subpattern `CAV-\d\s` inside it.
3. Finally replace whole match with 1st captured group i.e your first pattern.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KLnzaK/1/)**

**Python Code** ( tested in Python 3.5.2 )

```
import re

# Open file having genetic code. Use your file path.
new1 = 'C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\new1.txt'

# Create a new file for replaced data. Use your file path.
new2 = 'C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\new2.txt'

fp1 = open( new1, 'r') # Opening original file in read mode
fp2 = open( new2, 'w') # Opening replaced data in write mode.

lines = fp1.readlines() # Reading data from original file.
lines = ''.join(lines)  # Joined all lines as one line.

# Regex substitution on joined lines. Will repalce the duplicate data.
lines = re.sub(r'((CAV-\d+\s)[AGCT]+)(?:\n\2[AGCT]+)*', r'\1', lines)

#Writing replaced data to new file.

fp2.write(lines)

# Closing files.

fp1.close()
fp2.close()
```

Comment: Thank you @Rahul. Could you perhaps explain how you would incorporate that regex in the context of my question?. Thanks very much